# Calculating the probability of two consecutive heads occuring N times in M coin tosses?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I know the binomial distribution is used to calculate the probability of N heads in M coin tosses. But what if I want to calculate the number of ocurrences of particular pair of events, such as 'HH', in a random string?

Comment: How do you want to treat "three occurrences in a row". Is that "twice two", "one", or "none"? If it's "none", then the question can be rephrased "what is the probability that H is followed by H followed by not-H. You may find Markov chain theory useful if that is the case.

Comment: Suppose I am interested instead in exact "HT" (in that order) occurrences? Then I think that ambiguity is eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $N$ characters, and you have $n$ pairs of the combination `HT`, you can compute the number of different ways in which these can be arranged by considering the number of ways to partition "the other characters" ($N-2n$ characters) with $n$ partitions (where any occurrence of `HT` is a partition, and you could have two partitions at the same point).

Now you can put a partition at any one of $N-2n+1$ locations, and the partitions could all be in the same place. So you can consider that you have a total of $N-2n+1+n$ places to place one of $n$ partitions, for a total of $~^{N-n+1}C_n$ ways to fit them.

As long as the number $n\ll N$, this looks a lot like a binomial distribution; but it starts to diverge as that approximation breaks down.

Comment: $$^(N-n+1)C_n$$ is the binomial coefficient?